# object_size class is fragile

Tags: r, oop, object

Consider this snippet:

```
> a <- 1:1e7
> b <- 1:1e7
> (sizes <- sapply(c("a","b"),function(n) {
    s <- object.size(get(n))
    cat(n,": ")
    print(s,units="auto")
  }))
a : 38.1 Mb
b : 38.1 Mb
       a        b 
40000040 40000040
> class(sizes)
[1] "numeric"
> (s <- sum(sizes))
[1] 80000080
> class(s) <- "object_size"
> s
80000080 bytes
> print(s,units="auto")
76.3 Mb
```

Observe that

1. `sapply` removes the class `"object_size"` from `sizes` (`lapply` does not, but its result - a `list` - cannot be passed to `sum`).
2. `"object_size"` objects are printed with `units="B"` instead of `"auto"`

Both appear to be suboptimal; the value of `sizes` should be printed as

```
      a       b
38.1 Mb 38.1 Mb
```

My question is: is this just a bug, or is there some deep reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are any bugs here.

The truth of the matter is that the class of an R object is just an attribute like any other, and when `sapply` simplifies the result into a vector all attributes are stripped. You can remedy the problem by doing this, although the output is pretty ugly

```
> class(sizes) <- "object_size"
> sizes
40000040 bytes40000040 bytes
> sum(sizes)
80000080 bytes
```

As you noted `lapply` preserves the class (since it doesn't simplify), and if you want to calculate the sum on the result you can call the following.

```
> (sizes <- lapply(c("a","b"),function(n) {
    s <- object.size(get(n))
    cat(n,": ")
    print(s,units="auto")
  }))
a : 38.1 Mb
b : 38.1 Mb
[[1]]
40000040 bytes

[[2]]
40000040 bytes

> (s <- do.call(sum, sizes))
80000080
```

`sum` also strips the class since no function named `"sum.object_size"` is defined, and instead `.Primitive("sum")` is used, which again simplifies it to numeric. You can overload it, but @Greg Snow's answer using `Reduce` is more elegant.

```
> `sum.object_size` <- function(...){
    s <- sum(unlist(list(...)))
    class(s) <- "object_size"
    s
}
> do.call(sum, sizes)
80000080 bytes
```

The default behavior of `print.object_size` is to use `units="b"`, regardless of what you set in the `sapply` call. If you want to print them differently by default you have to overload `print.object_size`

```
> print.object_size <- function(..., units="auto")
    getFromNamespace("print.object_size", "utils")(..., units=units)
> sizes
[[1]]
38.1 Mb

[[2]]
38.1 Mb
```

**Edit: Note on "promise already under evaluation" errors**

Consider the following functions:

```
f <- function(x=1){
    h <- function(x) x
    h(x=x)
}
g <- function(x=1){
    h <- function(x=x) x
    h()
}
```

`f` will run without problems since `x` in `h(x=x)` is searched for in the environment of `f`. `g` on the other hand will cause an error since `x` in `h()` is searched for in the environment of `h`, where it is not defined.

Comment: wouldn't I see `promise already under evaluation` from `units=units`?

Comment: No because when you call the function returned from `getFromNamespace`, the variable `units` is searched for in the environment of `print.object_size`, not in the environment of the returned function itself. See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add together the elements of a list then consider using the `Reduce` function.  It will apply a binary operator (`+` in this case) to a vector or list.  The `+` operator does not strip the class and other attributes like `sapply` and `sum` do:

```
> a <- 1:1e7
> b <- 1:1e7
> (sizes <- lapply(c("a","b"),function(n) {
+ s <- object.size(get(n))
+     cat(n,": ")
+     print(s,units="auto")
+   }))
a : 38.1 Mb
b : 38.1 Mb
[[1]]
40000040 bytes

[[2]]
40000040 bytes

> 
> Reduce('+', sizes)
80000080 bytes
> print(.Last.value, units='auto')
76.3 Mb
```

Comment: The downside is that `Reduce` is quite a bit slower than `do.call(sum, ...)`

Comment: @GSee, but how much slower under what conditions?  For some cases the difference may be along the lines of `fortune(98)`.  In other cases it could make a noticeable difference, but still less than the time to type the command to add the class back on.  Other cases it could make a big enough difference to warrant using `do.call` and `sum`.